Shouldn't HorizontalStackLayout be equal to Orientation="Horizontal" with FillAndExpand .NET MAUI
Im making a simple application in .NET MAUI, but i noticed when i use HorizontalStackLayout, i don't get the same results as a StackLayout with Orientation="Horizontal" and HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand".
This is the xaml i'm using:
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Entry x:Name="InfoNombre" Placeholder="Nombre" Text="{Binding EditorPerfil.conta.InfoNombre}"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
    <Entry x:Name="InfoApellido" Placeholder="Apellido" Text="{Binding EditorPerfil.conta.InfoApellido}"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
</StackLayout>

Vs
<HorizontalStackLayout  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"> <!--Note that using HorizontalOptions="Fill" gets me the same result-->
    <Entry x:Name="InfoNombre" Placeholder="Nombre" Text="{Binding EditorPerfil.conta.InfoNombre}"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
    <Entry x:Name="InfoApellido" Placeholder="Apellido" Text="{Binding EditorPerfil.conta.InfoApellido}"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
</HorizontalStackLayout>

Image Below comparing results:
Design Result StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
Design Result HorizontalStackLayout

FillAndExpand and all other AndExpand types are deprecated in MAUI, if you want to do this now you need to use Grid
<Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*">
    <Entry x:Name="InfoNombre" Grid.Column="0" Placeholder="Nombre" Text="{Binding EditorPerfil.conta.InfoNombre}" />
    <Entry x:Name="InfoApellido" Grid.Column="1" Placeholder="Apellido" Text="{Binding EditorPerfil.conta.InfoApellido}" />
</Grid>


I directly started coding with MAUI, so i don't know much about xamarin, is both stacklayout and HorizontalStackLayout/VerticalStackLayout going to be deprecated and grid will be the new standard? Just to know, and start to change how i code, thanks in advance.

No it's the LayoutOptions that are deprecated, These were generally used with Stack, All you need to know is whenever you see AndExpand with anything that is deprecated and you need to design it with the new standards, This blog of mine would get you started with the correct understanding https://blog.stackademic.com/increasing-performance-in-a-net-maui-application-2be8ce7d995a
